# Solving $\det(A+Bx+Cx^2)=0$ where $A$, $B$, $C$ are $3\times3$-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> I would like to solve the following equation:
> \begin{align}
> \det (A+Bx+Cx^2) = 0
> \end{align}
> where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $3\times3$-matrices, which makes it a 6th-order polynomial.

In my specific case, I know that there is no real roots, i.e. the roots are of the form $x=x'\pm ix''$ (I don't know if this info is important).

If I can determine the coefficients, I can use numerical tools to solve this equation (such as `numpy.roots` in python), but other than writing out all coefficients by hand, I cannot come up with a good way to compute the coefficients. Of course, I could simply define a function $f(x) = \det(A+Bx+Cx^2)$ and make python find the roots, but then I'm not sure what would be the good starting values in order to make sure that all 6 solutions are found.

Comment: If you don't want to compute the coefficients by hand, you can compute them using a computer. But that's probably out of scope for MSE.

Comment: This seems more like a programing problem than a math problem. I'd suggest using a language that has better support for polynomials.  The easiest freely available one I can think of is Haskell.  There are also systems like Matlab or Mathematica, but they are not free (only trial versions), 
See https://imgur.com/a/C75NKKh

Comment: There's a somewhat related problem that I solved earlier. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071933/sign-of-the-real-parts-of-the-solutions-of-det-s2bsc-0-where-b-c-ar/3072943#3072943

Comment: Multiplying $\mathrm{det} C^{-1}$ (if it exists) puts $x^2$ only on the diagonal. It might make the computation a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) to do symbolic computations which is an open-source computer algebra system based on python.
Here is a sample code

```
A = Matrix([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,1,1]])
B = Matrix([[x,0,2*x],[8*x,2*x,4*x],[2*x,7*x,5*x]])
C = Matrix([[2*x*x,5*x*x,3*x*x],[3*x*x,2*x*x,3*x*x],[7*x*x,0,1*x*x]])
F = A + B + C;
det(F).expand()
```

The output will be

```
52*x^6 + 20*x^5 - 64*x^4 + 69*x^3 + 86*x^2 + 39*x
```

You can also see the above code [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzVLBV8E0sKcqs0IiONtQx0jGO1Yk2BtKGQNpQBwhjYzW5nJBVVegY6BhpVQDlLbQqQCwdEzAPxDIHYlMgD6jHGVkPUA4iAySNQSTIFjDPCEXMHMwz0DEE84GmuAFNcVTQVnACYmdrrpTUEg03Tb3UioLEvBQNTQAV6jMS&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Sage allows much more than just numerical calculations. You can use give an arbitrary matrix as input. For example

```
var('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i')
A = Matrix([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]])
B = Matrix([[a*x,0,2*x],[8*x,2*x,4*x],[2*x,7*x,5*x]])
C = Matrix([[b*2*x*x,5*x*x,3*x*x],[3*x*x,2*x*x,3*x*x],[7*x*x,0,1*x*x]])

F = A + B + C;
det(F).expand()
```

gives answer in terms of $a,b,c,$ etc.

**Edit**

If you calculate the polynomial then you are one step away from finding roots. In the case of SageMath it is too simple.

This

`(det(F)).roots(x, ring = CC)`

returns a list that contains roots whenever the coefficients are complex numbers.

Comment: Finding the determinant is actually not very useful. They would then have to feed it into a polynomial solver. The simplest thing is to just ask for the eigenvalues of F.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ and all the entries of the matrices are real, then taking the complex conjugates of everything leaves the equation unchanged, which means that for each solution $r_i$, the complex conjugate of $r_i$ should also be a solution. If none of the roots are real, then there are three pairs of roots, and so finding three roots can be sufficient if they are from different pairs.

It's not *too* onerous to work out the coefficients by hand, but Wolfram Alpha can find the determinate of a matrix in terms of a variable, and there probably are also Python libraries that can do so as well. [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) may be able to do it, or you could write your own function (note that one formula for the determinant is simply taking all possible diagonal of a permutation of the matrix, multiplying by the sign of the permutation, and then taking the sum). You can also just ask for the eigenvalues (they are the roots of the characteristic polynomial).

As you find eigenvalues, if you confine yourself to column space orthogonal to the eigenvectors of the eigenvalues you've found so far, then the eigenvalue you get from that column space will be a new eigenvalue (considering multiplicity). That is, you can pick a vector, multiply by the matrix over and over again until it stabilizes into an eigenvector, then pick a vector orthogonal to that eigenvector, multiply by the matrix over and over again to find another eigenvector, pick a vector orthogonal to the eigenvectors found so far, etc.